# How to remove the delay in the switch windows function in Ubuntu

Tags: application-switcher

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and notice a horrible delay (about half a second or more) in the switch windows function (I've replaced the default alt+tab for switching windows / the ungrouped function). So the gnome extension won't work unfortunately.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was not related to an intentional delay. This was because the machine itself was slow. I fixed the issue by installing cpu power manager extension in Gnome.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/945/cpu-power-manager/

It is also possible to switch the cpu governor's into performance instead of powersave but I prefer to have the ability to easily select a profile.

This changed my laptop speed greatly.